# projectRaster() error messages

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, rgdal

This code worked perfectly fine for me a few months ago, but now I am receiving error messages. I've tried it two different ways. Has the projectRaster() function been deprecated or syntax changed?

```
canopy_UTM16 <- projectRaster(from=canopy_east, crs=CRS("+init=epsg:32616"),method = "bilinear")

Error in CRS("+init=epsg:32616") : NA

canopy_UTM16 <- projectRaster(from=canopy_east, to=JERCUTMpts,method = "bilinear")

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extent': no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rgdal::compare_CRS(projto, projfrom) :
  NULL source CRS comment, falling back to PROJ string
2: In rgdal::compare_CRS(projto, projfrom) : +init dropped in PROJ string
3: In wkt(pto) : CRS object has no comment
4: In rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  :
  Using PROJ not WKT2 strings
```

Here are the current projections:

```
crs(canopy_east)

CRS arguments:
 +proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m
+no_defs 

crs(JERCUTMpts)

CRS arguments:
 +init=epsg:32616 +proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
+towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: `Error in CRS("+init=epsg:32616") : NA` looks a bit worrying. What does `CRS("+init=epsg:32616")` print? For me I see `CRS arguments:  +proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`. Looks like a problem with your PROJ projection library if you get `NA` for that. What version of all these package (`raster`, `sp`, `rgdal`) are you on? Please edit the Q and add the info....

Comment: CRS("+init=epsg:32616") prints
Error in CRS("+init=epsg:32616") : NA

After I got this error, I updated all my R packages so I'm on the most recent version of them.

Comment: I think you can edit your question, remove all the raster stuff, and boil it down to that one line returning NA. Can you add the output from `library(rgdal)` - specifically the versions of GDAL and PROJ that it has loaded? Also add if this is Win/Mac/Linux.

Comment: Output from library(rgdal): part 1

Please note that rgdal will be retired by the end of 2023,
plan transition to sf/stars/terra functions using GDAL and PROJ
at your earliest convenience.

rgdal: version: 1.5-29, (SVN revision 1165M)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 7.2.1, January 1st, 2021, [PJ_VERSION: 721]

Comment: Output from library(rgdal): part 2

Path to PROJ shared files: C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj
PROJ CDN enabled: FALSE
Linking to sp version:1.4-6
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading sp or rgdal.
Overwritten PROJ_LIB was C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj

Attaching package: ‘rgdal’

The following object is masked from ‘package:terra’:

    project

Warning message:
package ‘rgdal’ was built under R version 4.1.3 

This is in Windows.